# df - size doesn't equal used+available

Tags: hard-disk, disk-usage

I have such line when running `df`:

```
/dev/sda4                 47G     45G    0   /
```

I have all those error messages that there is no space left on the device. I rebooted system and nothing changed. I also have free inodes (used about 30%). Drive SMART days tells that everything is OK.

What can be the cause? How to fix it? Deleting files doesn't increase the available space.

Output of `lsblk --fs`:

```
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL          UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                
├─sda1 vfat    EFI            67E3-17ED                            
├─sda2 ext4    data           05fb1d77-ca58-482c-be30-d1bc23a2e7d0 /home/enedil/data
├─sda3 hfsplus Linux HFS+ ESP 96a17c8a-ac44-30f3-b436-ff173b605c74 /boot/efi
└─sda4 ext4                   e0b1deed-2cf8-4967-a813-538affd72a75 /
```

These are outputs of command I was asked for:

https://git.io/fjUt1

This in turn is the of `smartctl -s on -a /dev/sda`:

```
~ $ sudo smartctl -s on -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-4.20.15-100.fc28.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Apple SD/SM/TS...E/F/G SSDs
Device Model:     APPLE SSD SM0128G
Serial Number:    S23CNYAG426087
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 900000000
Firmware Version: BXW1JA0Q
User Capacity:    121,332,826,112 bytes [121 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Mar 26 01:56:53 2019 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
SMART Enabled.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       12364
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   065   065   000    Old_age   Always       -       34430
169 Unknown_Apple_Attrib    0x0013   221   221   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1052311028192
173 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0032   183   183   100    Old_age   Always       -       1297113874815
174 Host_Reads_MiB          0x0022   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       24044320
175 Host_Writes_MiB         0x0022   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       15890436
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       537
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   051   033   000    Old_age   Always       -       49 (Min/Max 5/67)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

Warning! SMART Selective Self-Test Log Structure error: invalid SMART checksum.
SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
  255        0    65535  Read_scanning was never started
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Are you using LVM? What is/are the filesystem(s) of your partition(s)?

Comment: 5% by default is reserved space. That filesystem is full.

Comment: @jordanm well, that happened instantly, a few minutes before I posted the question, I don't believe this is the case here.

Comment: @Paradox I have / on ext4, separate ext4 for my stuff, separate boot. No swap. No lvm.

Comment: @Paradox  The device would show `/dev/mapper/somenamevg` if it was lvm, likely

Comment: @enedil Can you show us the output of a SMART analysis tool such as `smartontools`? If you can run it at this point...

Comment: @enedil  Please also provide the filesystem that is used on the device. You can do `lsblk --fs` to find that out. Assuming you have `ext4` filesystem, please run `dumpe2fs /dev/sda4 | less` and provide values for `Block size` , `Block count`, `Reserved block count` and `Free blocks`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy  see updated question.

Comment: @Paradox , you too

Comment: @enedil Odd, you can't paste them when you click "edit" button on the question ? What about paste.ubuntu.com ? If that works for you, please post there and provide link to the paste.  As for where the data could have gone,  you can analyze that with `sudo ncdu -x /` command. Chances are you don't have it  installed, so if it's Debian based system, use `sudo apt-get install ncdu`. Likely you have a lot of cache from applications or large log file(s)

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy the output is there now. I can't install ncdu as there is no free space left. As for smart data, I probably don't have cli for that, but gnome disks report everything's fine.

Comment: Regarding the cause, if you have a tool like `htop`, or `atop` you can find out which process is writing to disk a lot.

Comment: @Tim *no process* is writting a lot. I don't have problems with processes,  I have a problem that reported used space is not actual free space and I can't write *anything*, not even a single byte. Certainly it isn't because some process writes data to my drive

Comment: @enedil Silly question, is it a HDD or a SSD? With `smartontools`, yes you have CLI. But is it installed? Since you cannot install anything, it's hard to diagnose what's happening.

Comment: @Paradox I found it, it's called `smartctl` on Fedora: https://git.io/fjU34

Comment: @enedil `smartontools` is the package. `smartctl` is one of the commands of it, this is why. Could you edit the question with the output of `sudo smartctl -s on -a /dev/sda`?

Comment: @Paradox : done